# How do I use Ghostscript with Python? converting images from eps to png / jpg/ pdf

Tags: python, ghostscript, postscript

Question(s):
I am trying to get a turtle graphic window to save as a jpg.  Presently I can get it to save as a .ps or .eps file.

```
can=turtle.getscreen().getcanvas()
can.postscript(file="test1.eps")
```

From here,  I was hoping to use Ghostscript to convert the file to jpg/png/pdf.

Using the ghostscript documentation, it looks like this would work: (https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.22/Use.htm#Invoking)

```
ps2pdf file.ps
```

Here is my dilemma.  I cannot install ghostscript to my boot drive.  I am on a network so this prevents me.  I do have a drive I can install to, but I don't know if that will work with ghostscript and python.  Any ideas?

GHOSTSCRIPT : I am not sure how ghostscript works with python (or otherwise).  I tried to log into the IRC chat on the ghostscript site, but that doesn't seem active for non-paying customers.

Comment: If you can get it to work from a command line, you can call it from Python. But program installation is off topic for this site.

Comment: The IRC channel #ghostscript is entirely active, its simply that 'netrate' is logging in at a time when all the developers are offline, We're based in Europe and the US, and there's nobody there at 1 am. He logged in at 1pm, but disappeared before anyone could answer. The #ghostscript IRC channel is intended primarily for open source users, we don't expect our commercial customers to use it at all (though they are welcome to if they want to) <continued>

Comment: As I mentioned on IRC (it'll be in the logs) Ghostscript doesn't need to be 'installed' at all, its happy to be run from anywhere, but with no information on the OS I can't be specific.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I will try again the IRC channel at a more appropriate time.  And I am NOT using ghostscript for commercial use.